# Problem with Queueing system using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have an array of names : Queue Andrew, Queue Alex, Queue Amy, Alex John, Alex Peter, John Jamie, Jamie Jack, John Adam

The function i'm trying to make will queue these names up. Those with Queue in the name will be added normally, those names with another persons' name infront will queue behind those names in the queue. So the answer for the array given above would be Andrew, Alex, John, Jamie, Jack, Adam, Peter, Amy.

This is the function i used to do this :

```
def test(arr):
    timer =0
    usedname ="pop"
    newlist=[]
    for i in arr:
        new_string = i.replace("MainQueue ","")
        newlist.append(new_string)
    ans=newlist
    for i in range(len(newlist)):
        if (len(newlist[i].split()) > 1):
            x = newlist[i].split() 
            y = ans.index(x[0])  
            name=x[1]  
            if x[0] == usedname:
                timer+=1
                newlist.remove(newlist[i])
                ans.insert(y+timer,name)
            else:
                timer =1
                newlist.remove(newlist[i])
                ans.insert(y+timer,name)
                usedname = x[0];
    print(' '.join(ans))
```

But the result i get is Andrew Alex John Adam Jamie Jack Peter Amy

I have no idea what i need to change to go about doing this and i feel like my attempted solution might be too complicated.

Comment: Does the problem require you to handle enqueuing behind people who aren't already in the queue? Or can you guarantee that when the name is "Alex John", "Alex" is already in the queue?

Comment: yeap, that is always guaranteed, When alex john is mentioned, alex will already be in the queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this function satisfies your requirements:

```
input_array = ["Queue Andrew", "Queue Alex", "Queue Amy", "Alex John", "Alex Peter", "John Jamie", "Jamie Jack", "John Adam"]

def test(arr):
    result = []
    for elem in arr[:]:
        a, b = elem.split()
        if a == "Queue":
            result.append(b)
            arr.remove(elem)
    i = len(arr) #starts at the end of the list (for iterating in reverse)
    while 0 < len(arr): # only as long as there are names left
        i -= 1 # next element (normally i += 1 but reversed)
        if i < 0: # if loop reached the front of the list, start over from the end.
            i = len(arr)-1 #start again from the end
        a, b = arr[i].split()
        if a in result:
            result.insert(result.index(a) + 1, b)
            arr.remove(arr[i])
    return result

print(test(input_array))

#prints ['Andrew', 'Alex', 'John', 'Jamie', 'Jack', 'Adam', 'Peter', 'Amy']
```

First it adds all "Queue Name" elements to the list.
Then it iterates over the remaining entries until `arr` is empty (in reverse order so that the result is correct.), inserting the name (`result.insert()`) behind the index of the other name (`result.index(a)+1`)

This algorithm has worst case `O(n^2)` if I am not mistaken and best case `O(n)`.

#### EDIT

Iterating over the list in reverse order makes it a bit more complicated. Instead of starting at `i=0` we need to start at `i=len(arr)`. Then for each iteration we decrement `i` by 1.
The loop iterates multiple times over the array until it is empty. So if `i` reaches the 0th element it needs to start over from the end of `arr`.

Comment: Hi, can you explain how the while loop works ? until the contents of the if statement, im having trouble understanding it. Can i also ask, how do you determine its Big Oh ?

Comment: I added some more comments and an explanation. Hope it is better now. As for the BigO, I meant worst-case. Because we iterate in reverse, we will probably only add a couple of names for each round and therefor need n round to add every item.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks so much for your help, I didn't think to iterate backwards !